# Tango: How to get depth frame from the tango device using Java

Tags: java, google-project-tango, tango

I am developing a measurement tool just like Measure It. I am stuck in aligning the depth frame with the color camera frame. I am able to get an average depth of the point cloud but can't get the complete depth frame.

1. Is there any simple way provided by Tango SDK to get the depth frame ?
2. The color camera frame and depth frame has different resolutions, how can I align them ? Does Tango SDK does it or do I have to projec the depth frame to camera frame myself ? How do I do it ?

I am using the Tango Java SDK along with Android Studio.

p.s: Yes I have read similar questions posted on SO but some were unanswered and others did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the new released point to point measurement example in both C and Java.

https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-c

https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java

Comment: Thanks Jason. This really helped me.